# Error: A value of type 'RenderObject?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'AbstractNode?'

Tags: flutter, render

`../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/sliver_tools-0.2.9/lib/src/sliver_stack.dart:282:55: Error: A value of type 'RenderObject?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'AbstractNode?'.

- 'RenderObject' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart' ('../../development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart').
- 'AbstractNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart' ('../../development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart').
  final AbstractNode? targetParent = renderObject.parent;
  ^
  ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/sliver_tools-0.2.9/lib/src/sliver_stack.dart:283:54: Error: The method 'markNeedsLayout' isn't defined for the class 'AbstractNode?'.
- 'AbstractNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart' ('../../development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'markNeedsLayout'.
  if (targetParent is RenderObject) targetParent.markNeedsLayout();
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/mahirandigital/Documents/development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy' line: 1297
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command '/Users/mahirandigital/Documents/development/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1`

I got an error like this after I upgrade my gradle-wrapper.properties to 7.3
I upgraded my gradle-wrapper.properties because my flutter is not compatible with my JAVA version
so how can I solve this?
btw im re-opening my project after a month

I have tried flutter pub cache clean, flutter pub cache repair, flutter pub get but it didn't solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

My error was when Flutter version is 3.13.1, but when Flutter was upgraded to version 3.13.2, it worked.

I don't know how but it work well. I didn't have to create new project and copy all files and folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In my case flutter version was already latest. Sliver_tools was outdated, I did ```flutter pub upgrade``` which solved problem